# Query to fetch all objects sorted by a distinct property of the columns?

Tags: java, database, postgresql, hibernate, select

I'm using Hibernate and I would like to perform the following query:

```
SELECT e FROM Posicao e WHERE e.id IN (SELECT DISTINCT p.papel FROM Posicao p)
```

But I get the following:

> HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You
> might need to add explicit type casts.
> ********** Error **********
>
> ERROR: operator does not exist: integer = character varying

I believe it is lacking a casting command, but I can't figure it out. My column id consists of integers whereas the others consist of VARCHAR.

When I change e.id by e.papel, for instance, it works just fine, but that is not what I want.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You can cast:

```
select e from Posicao e where e.id in (select p.papel::int from Posicao p)
```

Not that I removed `distinct`, which is not necessary with `in`. The purpose of your query is still rather unclear, though. In any case, I would recommend using `exists` instead of `in`, since many databases tend to optimize it better:

```
select e 
from posicao p
where exists (select 1 from posicao p1 where p1.papel::int = p.id)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. It didn't work, I will have to add some more details.